# Extract PHP method in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to extract the selected lines to a PHP function?

I saw there is a way to do it for C#, but I did not find a way for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

No, not builtin at least.

Features like extract method have to be implemented per-language. Try filing a feature request against the PHP extension: https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues